# Как сделать анимацию движения/перелистывания слайдов со стрелками?

Tags: javascript

Осталось только сделать пролистывание контента, потому что его не видно из-за ширины экрана, а ширина экрана 1440р. В макете карусель стоит именно так, как-бы прячась за экраном.

```js
var carousel = document.querySelector('.js-carousel');
var carouselItems = Array.prototype.slice.apply(
  carousel.querySelectorAll('.js-carousel__item')
);
var pager = document.querySelector('.js-carousel__pager');
var prevButton = document.querySelector('.js-carousel__prev');
var nextButton = document.querySelector('.js-carousel__next');
var duration = 1000;
var activeItem = 0;

var prevInClasses = [
  'bounceInLeft',
  'animated',
  'is-active'
];

var prevOutClasses = [
  'bounceOutRight',
  'animated',
  
];

var nextInClasses = [
  'bounceInRight',
  'animated',
  'is-active'
];

var nextOutClasses = [
  'bounceOutLeft',
  'animated'
];

function clearClasses(el) {
  var classes = [].concat(
    prevInClasses,
    prevOutClasses,
    nextInClasses,
    nextOutClasses
  );
  
  el.classList.remove.apply(el.classList, classes);
}

function slidePrev() {
  if (activeItem === 0) return;
  activeItem -= 1;
  if (activeItem === 0) prevButton.disabled = true;
  nextButton.disabled = false;
  var current = carousel.querySelector('.is-active');
  var prev = carouselItems[activeItem];
  
  if (current) {
    clearClasses(current);
    current.classList.add.apply(current.classList, prevOutClasses);
  }
  
  clearClasses(prev);
  prev.classList.add.apply(prev.classList, prevInClasses);  
  updatePager();
  updateHeight();
}

function slideNext() {
  if (activeItem === carouselItems.length - 1) return;
  activeItem += 1;
  var current = carousel.querySelector('.is-active');
  var next = carouselItems[activeItem];
  
  if (activeItem === carouselItems.length - 1) nextButton.disabled = true;
  prevButton.disabled = false;
  
  if (current) {
    clearClasses(current);
    current.classList.add.apply(current.classList, nextOutClasses);
  }
  
  clearClasses(next);
  next.classList.add.apply(next.classList, nextInClasses);
  updatePager();
  updateHeight();
}

function updatePager() {
  pager.textContent = (activeItem + 1) + '/' + carouselItems.length;
}

function updateHeight() {
  carousel.style.height = carouselItems[activeItem].clientHeight + 'px';
}

function init() {
  carouselItems.forEach(function(item, idx) {
    if (idx === 0) {
      item.classList.add('is-active');
      return;
    }
    
    item.classList.add.apply(item.classList, prevOutClasses);
  });
  
  updateHeight();
  updatePager();
  
  // Event listeners
  prevButton.onclick = slidePrev;
  nextButton.onclick = slideNext;
}

window.addEventListener('load', init);
```

```css
*{padding: 0;margin: 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;grid-template-rows: auto;
font-family: inherit;color: inherit;font-size: inherit;
box-sizing: border-box;
scroll-behavior: smooth;}
.wrapper{max-height: 100%;overflow: hidden;}
.line{display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: space-between;}
/**//**//**//**//**//**/
.o-justifize {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.c-carousel {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 1400px;
  transition: 200ms all;
  transition-delay: 200ms;
  margin-left: 135px;
}

.c-carousel__item {
  width: 270px;
  height: 456px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.c-carousel__item.is-active {
  width: 500px;
  height: 456px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="c-carousel js-carousel line">
            <li class="c-carousel__item js-carousel__item"></li>
            <li class="c-carousel__item js-carousel__item"></li>
            <li class="c-carousel__item js-carousel__item"></li>
            <li class="c-carousel__item js-carousel__item"></li>
            <!-- <li class="c-carousel__item js-carousel__item"></li> -->
          </ul>
          
          <div class="o-justifize u-p">
            <button class="c-carousel__button js-carousel__prev" disabled>Prev</button>
            <div class="c-carousel__pager js-carousel__pager">1/5</div>
            <button class="c-carousel__button js-carousel__next">Next</button>
          </div>
```

Comment: Можете чуть более подробно описать что вам нужно:?

Comment: Пытался сделать класс с transiton, чтобы он добавлялся и была анимация передвижения. Затем с помощью keyframes, но там как бы не фиксируется значение - это анимация css просто, пока что так пытался

Comment: Т. е. надо что бы размер изменялся плавно?

Comment: Когда происходит клик по кнопке next, то класс active добавляется к следующему слайду, и так доходит до 4-го. Доходит и кнопка next не активна, затем пользователю станет активна кнопка prev, и он пойдет по слайдам в начало. Проблема в том, что конечный слайд не видно, так как он уходит за экран, и я подумал, что тут подойдет анимация перелистывания.

Comment: То есть, когда я нажимаю на next предыдущий слайд должен "отойти" влево, чтобы пользователь смог нормально прочитать контент внутри div`a

Comment: Затем, когда пользователь нажимает prev (влево), то перелистывание двигается вправо, и все div постепенно встают на прежние места, по мере возвращения к исходному первому слайду.